# кнопка по центру

Tags: java, button, jframe

подскажите, пожалуйста, какой метод располагает кнопку по центру панели JFrame

Answer (score 4):

Вам надо пользоваться [BorderLayout'ом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BorderLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BorderLayoutDemo.java) или [GridBagLayout'ом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java)